# Dynamic control of firebase storage security rules from database

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I want to have a dynamic control on storage rules from database. I mean it should check database nodes to allow read or write.
 But I cannot find a way. 
For example

```
match /files/{fileKey} {
  allow read: // here will check db to get result of allowRead 
  allow write: // here will check db to get result allowWrite
}
```

db:

```
files: {
  fileKey1: {
    allowRead: true,
    allowWrite: false
},
  fileKey2: {
    allowRead: true,
    allowWrite: true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to check the Firebase Database from Firebase Storage security rules.

You'll have to either embed the necessary information into your Storage security rules, or [embed it in the user's token as a custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).

Answer (score 0):

This feature is now in alpha and is available for those who opt in for their alpha program - I'll update this answer as soon as it's available for everyone.

One can apply to the alpha program using [this link](https://services.google.cn/fb/forms/firebasealphaprogram/) (or google it if the link is no longer working)

Comment: Good news! I will ckeck it out