# Creating Firebase Storage Security Rules Based on Firebase Database Conditions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Is it possible to assign Firebase Storage security rules based on evaluating a condition from data stored in Firebase Realtime Database?

For Example:

(1) Firebase Storage Model:

```
{ userPhotos/:
       "JohnUID" : {
           "JohnURL": john.jpeg,
       },

       "JaneUID" : {
            "JaneURL": jane.jpeg,
        },

        "AbbyUID" : {
             "AbbyURL": abby.jpeg,
        },
 }
```

(2) Firebase Realtime Database Model:

```
{ userReadPermissions: 
       "JohnUID": {
           "JohnUID": true,
           "JaneUID": true,
           "AbbyUID": false,
       },

       "JaneUID": {
           "JohnUID": true,
           "JaneUID": true,
           "AbbyUID": false,
       },

       "AbbyUID": {
           "JohnUID": false,
           "JaneUID": false,
           "AbbyUID": true,
       },
}
```

The goal is to only allow read permissions to the photo URL storage node (1) according to the conditions set by each UID in Firebase RTD (2).

For example, John's photo would only be visible to John & Jane, but not Abby, as the per the permissions defined by each user in (2).

Similarly, Jane's photo would only be visible to John & Jane, but not Abby, while Abby's photo would be visible to Abby only, and to neither John or Jane.

Is there a way to cross-reference conditions defined across these Firebase services to define security rules accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to access the Firebase Realtime Database from Firebase Storage security rules.

You will either have to encode the read permissions directly into the Storage security rules (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086446/how-to-restrict-access-to-files-to-group-members)), or encode the "membership" into a small set of [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).

Also see:

- [How to restrict access to files to group members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086446/how-to-restrict-access-to-files-to-group-members)
- [Dynamic control of firebase storage security rules from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48379745/dynamic-control-of-firebase-storage-security-rules-from-database)
- [Controlling Data Access Using Firebase Auth Custom Claims](https://medium.com/google-developers/controlling-data-access-using-firebase-auth-custom-claims-88b3c2c9352a)

Comment: Thank you! I never updated this... I ended up customizing the permissions using metadata according to the first link you provided above.